# groovy MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.getFileSystem()

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to map all the xml files in a directory, like this:

```
static Map<String, String> mapFilesInDirectory(Path dir) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = Files.find(dir, 0, { path, basicFileAttributes -> basicFileAttributes.isRegularFile() && path.endsWith(".xml") })
            .collect(Collectors.toMap({path -> path.getFileName()}, { path -> ResourceUtils.getResourceAsString(path) }
            ))
    return map
}
```

And I am calling that method like this:

```
def static importContentFromDirectory(String directoryName, String resourcePath, String importConfigurationFile = null) {
    Path directoryPath = resourcePath+directoryName as Path
    Map<String, String> map = mapFilesInDirectory(directoryPath)

    importContentWithSeveralFiles(directoryName, map, importConfigurationFile)
}
```

And I am getting this error when I call mapFilesinDirectory: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.getFileSystem() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Can't figure it out.

Comment: Please add your imports and a sample of what you expect in the map.

Answer (score 1):

It had to do with the way I was getting Path.
I changed the following:

```
Path directoryPath = resourcePath+directoryName as Path
```

To this:

```
Path directoryPath = Paths.get(resourcePath+directoryName)
```

What I have is still not quite right but that particular error is now gone.